# Message Queue Design

Tags: message-queue

Here's the scenario

I have an offline application and when a user presses publish I want to

- Print 2 copies to printer A
- Print 1 copies to printer B
- Print 3 copies to printer C
- Send txt message to recipient A
- Send txt message to recipient B
- Export data to external system
- Sync data with online website
- Various other jobs could be added to the list

So what I am asking is there a better structure i can use, I was hoping to avoid a full message queuing system as this is a standalone desktop app.

I started off my creating a database table for each task and putting the job number in the list, then processing it, and deleting it from the list once complete.

While this works fine, there are issues when the job fails, I don't have a retry timeout or anything, and every time I add a task (not often), I have to add a new table, which is not so good.

Other problems I have encountered are that all the tasks have different parameters, should i just be using json or something to store those parameters? at the moment each table in the database has different columns for the parameters

Comment: Could this be a candidate for a Spring Batch application, where you could chain the tasks for a given job?http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an ideal job for a MQ.  Upon publishing you add the jobs to the queue(s) with whatever parameters are appropriate.  You then need 10 (or whatever) readers to read the messages and manage the printing/texting/exporting etc.  From what you have described there is no point in rolling your own using a database.

Timeout/Retry is a business problem you need to work out how to alert and address.  It's less of a technical issue than you may think.

Personally I'd have one message type/queue per target.  JSON or other format will depend on your platform.  Generally you just serialise an object with all the data onto the queue using whatever mechanism your platform provides.  Worst case, you make XML then add that to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need MQ if your application is not going to scale across systems. Message Queues are best suited for distributed systems. You have mentioned that its going to be a desktop application.

While designing applications you'll have to identify components from the requirements given. What you have currently is a set of requirements. You need to break them down into components that can be reused.

Retry and timeout are parameters for a task ... When you take a task through the components you can handle them.

You will need a database,  but not a high scaling database. All you need a persistence store.